# GWT - What is the maximum number of elements that can be put in a JSONArray?

Tags: java, json, gwt

In my GWT application, I am having a JSONArray object. I take an input string and do some processing on a large number of files that are opened and insert elements in the JSONArray object based on some condition.

On giving some input that would insert a large number of elements in the JSONArray, I get this exception:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

If I give an input, with which there wouldn't be relatively less number of elements being put in the JSONArray object, I don't get such an exception.

Is there any limit on the the number of elements that can be put in a JSONArray?

If so, what is the number?

Comment: Please show the code that is populating the array.  Also, how many is a "large number"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is 4,294,967,295 elements.

Usually, this message indicates that you created an infinite loop somewhere in your code.